# dplyr-like row manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

let's say I have a data.frame

```
A B C
x q 4
x p 2
y q 0
y p 8
```

I want to select all rows with `B==q` and calculate the corresponding mean of `C` and add it as an additional row with let's say `A==z`, `B==o` and for `C` the just caluclated mean.

This is basically what dplyr does with columns but applied to rows. My question is thus: Is there any way to apply dplyr operations instead of columns on rows? Even better of course would be dplyr-like package for row-manipulation.

(My actual data.frame consists of course of a lot more rows and columns)

Best regards

Comment: Could you show expected output based on this input?

Comment: You have no by row operations here as per your description. The mean of `C` is just a normal vector mean. If you want to do this by group, see `group_by`. If you want a certain subset, see `filter`. Eventually you'll probably need `rbind` or `bind_rows`.

Comment: In other words this `rbind(df, data.frame(A = 'z', B = 'o', C = mean(df$C[df$B == 'q'])))` ?

Comment: Yes, I have to admit I was a bit unclear. I indeed meant a grouped mean. The answer by cafe876 was exactly what I was looking for :) (the verb was bind_rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this using dplyr is as follows:

```
df <-  read.table(header = TRUE, 
text = "A B C
  x q 4
  x p 2
  y q 0
  y p 8")

library(dplyr)

df %>% bind_rows(df %>% 
                filter(B=="q") %>% 
                summarize(C = mean(C)) %>%
                mutate(A = "z", B = "o")
              )
```

Comment: perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say use group_by and summarise function in dplyr

```
df %>% group_by (B) %>% group_by(A) %>% summaries(mean(C))
```